# How to use the wire service to get field from child Object?

Tags: soql, lightning-web-components, master-detail

This seems to be pretty simple but I kinda lost right now. I want to create a LWC based on two custom objects which has a master-detail relationship.

I have a 'master' object **Product__c**

- Name
- Id
- etc

and the 'detail' object **Product_Version__c**

- Name
- Id
- Product__c (Master-Detail (Product))
- Pre_Version__c (Lookup(Product Version))
- etc

I need to get field 'Id' and 'Pre_Version__c' from **Product_Version__c** based on the **Product__c.Id**

I know the SOQL command to get them:

```
SELECT (SELECT Id, Name, Pre_Version__c From Product_Versions__r),Name FROM Product__c WHERE Id = 'abcde'
```

I also know how to use wire to get fields from an object, but not from the child/detail object.

How do I get fields from the child/detail object (**Product_Version__c**) based only on Product__c.Id?

**lwc.js**

```
import { LightningElement,api,wire} from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getRecordUi } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import productVersion from '@salesforce/schema/Product_Version__c';

const fields = [
    'Product__c.Name',
    'Product__c.Id'
];

const productVersionFields = [
     'Product_Version__c.Name',
     'Product_Version__c.Id',
     'Product_Version__c.Pre_Version__c',
]

export default class ProductVersion extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;
recordId= 'abcde';
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
product;

get name() {
    return this.product.data ? this.product.data.fields.Name.value : "";
}

get id() {
    return this.product.data ? this.product.data.fields.Id.value : "";
}

 @wire(getRecordUi, { recordIds: '$recordId', childRelationships: "Product.Product_Versions" })
    productVersion;

    //Product Version object
    get preVersion() {
        return this.productVersion.data ? this.productVersion.data.fields.Pre_Version__c .value : "";
    }

    get childId() {
        return this.productVersion.data ? this.productVersion.data.fields.Id.value : "";
    }
}
```

Comment: @glls Hi, thank you for the link. I have edited the code and it is still not working. In my case, I only know the Record ID of the parent object. How do I dynamically get the ID of the child object?